# Centripetal acceleration and gravitational acceleration on a thread

Tags: homework-and-exercises, centripetal-force

This is a question from my physics textbook.

*"A $200$ gram weight is suspended in a $2.5m$ long thread in the roof. The weight is pulled out sideways, creating the angle $\alpha$ and is then released. The weight then swings back and forth. What is the maximum angle $\alpha$before the thread snaps? The thread snaps at above $2.6N$"*

This is the diagram I drew:
[image: diagram]

And this is how I attempt to solve it:

The force that the thread will be subjected to is the sum of the centripetal force, and the gravitational force. The latter is at its maximum when the thread is perpendicular with the roof. I.e. $9.8m/s^2 \times 0.200kg = 1.96N$. This leaves $0.64N$ for the centripetal force.

The centripetal force is:
$mv^2\over r$.

To find $v^2$ I use the fact that energy is conserved and set up the equality:

${mv^2\over 2} = mgh$

$v^2 = 2gh = 19.6h$

(1) So, the centripetal force is: $19.6hm \over r$

$h$ is found through trigonometry:

${cos (\alpha)} = {h \over r}$

$h = r \times cos(\alpha)$

Returning to (1):

$0.64N = {{19.6(r \times cos(\alpha)) \times m} \over r}$

$3.2m/s^2 = 19.6 \times cos(\alpha)$

$cos(\alpha) = 0.16$

$\alpha = 81^o$

However, the answer in the book is $33^o$, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct. While conserving the energy and writing $\frac{mv^2}{2} = mg\Delta h$, the $\Delta h$ is the change in the height of the mass which is (2.5-$h$) meters as the mass comes in a vertical position ($h$ is the starting height of the mass which depends on the angle $\alpha$). You should be able to get the answer correct if you incorporate this correction.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was my mistake, and incorporating that correction led to the correct answer.